Getting IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 413.1 - request entity too large in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
I have spent a day or 2 just trying to get my API to work with IIS so I can deploy it to Azure. I want to upload a file larger than 100MB. It works locally with profile set to https, but when I change to IIS Express, it's a nightmare.
Here is my code - Program.cs:
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.

    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MaxRequestBodySize = null; // Set to 250 MB
    });

    builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(opt =>
    {
        opt.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null; // Set to unlimited
    });

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
}

My controller looks like this:
[HttpPost("file")]
[RequestSizeLimit((250 * 1024 * 1024))] // Set to 250 MB
public async Task<IActionResult> File(IFormFile file)
{
    var fileName = file.FileName;

    return Ok(fileName);
}

Any help would be appreciated, I am trying to deploy my API and test. When I deploy it with https profile, I am getting

InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server


This question is similar to: Asp.net Core 2.0 RequestSizeLimit attribute not working and Remove 30MB upload limit on IIS express . If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
